# EditText to Integer (Android)

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-edittext, countdowntimer

I am attempting to convert an EditText, which is of type number in xml, to an Integer in order to calculate the value in seconds.

```
    hoursIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hoursET);
    minIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minET);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisp);

    inHr = Integer.parseInt(hoursIn.getText().toString());
    inMin = Integer.parseInt(minIn.getText().toString());

    hoursMs = hrsToMs(inHr);
    minMs = minToMs(inMin);
    totalTime = hoursMs + minMs;
```

When I comment the lines where inHr and inMin are initialized I get no error in runtime, however when I leave the code as it is above I get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dit.assignment3/dit.assignment3.Timer}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

I have also attempted this while getting the same error starting at the same line of code:

```
    final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(totalTime, 1000);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (hoursIn != null)
            {
                inHr = Integer.parseInt(hoursIn.getText().toString());
                hoursMs = hrsToMs(inHr);

            }
            if (minIn != null)
            {
                inMin = Integer.parseInt(minIn.getText().toString());
                minMs = minToMs(inMin);
            }
            else
            {
                textViewTime.setText("PLEASE GIVE A TIME");
            }
            totalTime = hoursMs + minMs;
            timer.start();
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: looks like you're not entering text

Comment: It's given in the error itself. Invalid int: "" You must have not entered the text. It's blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain that this codes blocks are exactly same as you've shown here. That means You are directly initializing `EditText` and immediately calling `getText()` method which causes `Exception`.

There wont be any value immediately after initialization so that you are getting `NumberFormatException` when calling `Integer.parseInt` to empty value.

So I suggest you to put these codes inside some event like `buttonClicked` like here, so that you can be sure that you've entered some texts. And It's better checking if `empty` as well,

```
public void buttonClicked(View v){
    inHr = Integer.parseInt(hoursIn.getText().toString());
    inMin = Integer.parseInt(minIn.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: So in an onClickListener type method? I am using it for a timer. 
Thank you

Comment: @Caoimhe Then did it work, or still some issue left ?

Comment: I managed to get it working by using this: 
 start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (! hoursIn.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    inHr = Integer.parseInt(hoursIn.getText().toString());
                    hoursMs = hrsToMs(inHr);
                }
....

Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciate it

Comment: You are most welcome, They both are the same way. One is anonymous and another is method based. great to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` whenever you try to parse an empty string to Integer. Thus you need to check whether the EditText is empty or not.

You could easily do that as below

```
if (hoursIn.getText().toString().matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

**OR**

you can simply do a check as below

```
if (hoursIn.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Or even better, use TextUtils.isEmpty().

Comment: Yeah sure...there are a number of other options too for that..Anyway thanks...:) @ElDuderino

Answer (score 0):

First you have to put the lines where you are reading from edittext inside some event like click of a button. Then check whether anything is entered in the edittext or not, then use try/catch clause to convert it into number.

Try this code.
Add a button to your activity xml file:

```
   <Button 
   android:height="wrap_content"
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="myClickHandler" />



    hoursIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hoursET);
    minIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minET);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisp);

    public void myClickHandler(View v){
     if (hoursIn.getText().toString().matches("") ||  minIn.getText().toString().matches("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
     } else {
          try {
            inHr = Integer.parseInt(hoursIn.getText().toString());
            inMin = Integer.parseInt(minIn.getText().toString());
            hoursMs = hrsToMs(inHr);
            minMs = minToMs(inMin);
            totalTime = hoursMs + minMs;
            Log.i("success");
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter number only",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
         }
      }        
    }
```